# Adicionando vírgula em uma string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

Boa pessoal e possível adicionar vírgula em uma string exemplo:

```
a = '1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_'
```

para que ela fique assim `a = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7....`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Faça o seguinte:

```
lst = list(a) // transforma sua string em lista 
txt = ",".join(lst) // coloca vírgula entre as letras
```

Note que isso pode ser feito em apenas um passo:

```
a = ",".join(a)
```

Comment: Obrigado Eduardo isso mesmo.

Comment: De nada :) @GlaucioFonseca

Comment: Você também pode ser mais direto né usando:
>>> a = "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_"
>>> a = ",".join(a)
>>> a
'1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,_'

Comment: Por que não `a = ",".join("1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_")`?... calma, é só pra descontrair.

Comment: hahahahahahahahahahah... ufa :)

Comment: hahahahaha e isso :)

Comment: Na verdade eu uso muito o console python pra ficar fazendo essas doidiera minha kkkkk