# Como concatenar strings em uma lista?

Tags: python-3.x, string, lista, concatenação-de-string

Se eu tiver uma lista de objetos tipo string e quiser concatenar todos esses itens, como fazer isso ?
 Por exemplo:

`row1 = ['___', '___', '___']`

Gostaria de imprimir: `'___|___|___'`

Consegui fazer assim, mas não é muito prático: `line1 = row1[0] + "|" + row1[1] + "|" + row1[2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O tipo *string* possui um método chamado [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) que faz o serviço:

```
line1 = '|'.join(row1)
```

Ele concatenará todos os valores da lista adicionando o caractere entre eles. O `join` tende a ser mais eficiente que a própria concatenação (1) e permite informar diferentes caracteres (2).

- (1): [O que faz o join() ser tão superior se comparado a outras técnicas de concatenação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153322/5878)
- (2): [Adicionando vírgula em uma string](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102103/5878)